# PGPlugin.h was not found when I was using Childbrowser in Phonegap

Tags: html, cordova

I tried to use Childbrowser in phonegap 1.7.0 in my project.But it won't run as my expectation.

Error: ' PGPlugin.h' file is not found.

How to obtain the file 'PGPlugin.h'?

Does anyone meet this problem?

Does phonegap plugin not support the latest phonegap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use this version of the ChildBrowser instead as it is updated for use with Cordova.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ChildBrowser

Comment: It works.Thank you very much.I had just asked a silly question. :-p

Comment: But it seems that I meet another problem.I open a web page by Childbrowser,but when I press 'done' Childbrowser open the page 'about blank' and never hide.